# Using routes to generate URLs in a Symfony task

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am running [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS.

I have written a Symfony task that generates a report which contains links (URLs).

Here is a snippet of the `execute()` method in my task class:

```
  protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    //create a context
    sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);
    sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('Url', 'Asset', 'Tag'));

    ...
    $url = url_for("@foobar?cow=marymoo&id=42");

    // Line 1
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">This is a test</a>';

    // Line 2
    echo link_to('This is a test', $url); 
  }
```

The route name is defined like this:

```
foobar:
  url: /some/fancy/path/:cow/:id/hello.html
  param: {  module: mymodule, action: myaction }
```

When this is run, the generated link is:

**Line 1** produces this output:

> ./symfony/symfony/some/fancy/path/marymoo/42/hello.html

instead of the expected:

> /some/fancy/path/marymoo/42/hello.html

**Line 2** generates an error:

> Unable to find a matching route to
>   generate url for params "array ( 
>   'action' => 'symfony',  'module' =>
>   '.',)".

Again, the expected URL is:

> /some/fancy/path/marymoo/42/hello.html

How may I resolve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To generate a URL in a task:

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
  $routing = $this->getRouting();
  $url = $routing->generate('route_name', $parameters);
}
```

We add a method to generate routing so that the production URL is always used:

```
   /**
   * Gets routing with the host url set to the url of the production server
   * @return sfPatternRouting
   */
  protected function getProductionRouting()
  {
    $routing = $this->getRouting();
    $routingOptions = $routing->getOptions();
    $routingOptions['context']['host'] = 'www.example.com';
    $routing->initialize($this->dispatcher, $routing->getCache(), $routingOptions);
    return $routing;
  }
```

Comment: +1 for the nice, succinct snippet which shows me how to solve this problem. I shall modify the code slightly to suit what I am doing, test it, if it works, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Where should i put this snippet? I can't call $this->getRouting() from  a task :/

Comment: You can use sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting() in a task.

Answer (score 3):

I you wanna to use standard helpers (like url_for) to generate url, maybe this code could help you:

```
  protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    // initialize the database connection
...
$context = sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);

$routing = $context->getRouting();
$_options = $routing->getOptions();
$_options['context']['prefix'] = "";// "/frontend_dev.php" for dev; or "" for prod
$_options['context']['host'] = sfConfig::get('app_url_base');
$routing->initialize($this->dispatcher, $routing->getCache(),$_options);
$context->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
$context->set('routing',$routing);    
//$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = sfConfig::get('app_url_base'); // ---> I don't remember why I have this on my code, shouldn't be necessary
...
```

Then, you can use **url_for** function **everywhere** with absolute=true parameter magically working.

Of course, you need to add a *url_base* definition in your app.yml (or maybe you can leave it harcoded)

Comment: thansk a lot, this worked for me. little comment: `$options` is used for the task command line options, so a different name for the variable avoids problems..

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and found the following Code Snippet: http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/378

The solution is rather similar, however it extends the ProjectConfiguration. The advantage of this approach is, that it works transparently in modules as as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak default request options for commands (sfTask) in the project configuration script `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration {

    public function setup() {
        ...
        $this->dispatcher->connect('command.pre_command', array('TaskWebRequest', 'patchConfig'));
    }

}

class TaskWebRequest extends sfWebRequest {

    public function __construct(sfEventDispatcher $dispatcher, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array(), $options = array())
    {
        $options['no_script_name'] = true;
        $options['relative_url_root'] = '';
        parent::__construct($dispatcher, $parameters, $attributes, $options);
    }

    public static function patchConfig(sfEvent $event) {
        sfConfig::set('sf_factory_request', 'TaskWebRequest');
    }

}
```