# Generate URL in a symfony 1.4 task

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have to generate an URL in a task but I get an incorrect url of type:

```
./symfony/user/edit/id
```

when I need

```
/user/edit/id
```

My first try was:

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
    $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $options['env'], true);
    $this->context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
    $baseurl = $this->context->getController()->genUrl(array('module' => 'user','action' => 'edit', 'id' => $id));
    // ...
}
```

My second try, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285953/using-routes-to-generate-urls-in-a-symfony-task) gives the same incorrect url:

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{

    $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $options['env'], true);
    $this->context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
    $routing = $this->context->getRouting();
    $baseurl = $routing->generate('user_edit', array('id' => $id));
    // ...
}
```

How can I get the correct URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved adding the --application option!

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this->addOptions(array(
        new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev'),
        new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'frontend'),
    ));

    //...
}
```

I didn't know that it was required even if I write directly its name in the getApplicationConfiguration params.

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $options['env'], true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the solution from the [snippet](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/378)? I use this one in many projects.

I was also using almost the same second solution you describe but a bit different:

```
// you get the context the same way
$context = sfContext::createInstance($configuration);
$this->controller = $context->getController();

$baseurl = $this->controller->genUrl('user_edit?id='.$id);
```

Check parameters for [`genUrl`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWebController#method_genurl), you can give true/false as second argument for absolute url.

Comment: thanks, your solution don't work for me (same wrong url, also with absolute url)... will try the snippet